# DrawBitmap in Canvas Is Slow

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, android-drawable

**Here is my code Below**

```
public class GameController extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        public static int WIDTH =800;
        public static int HEIGHT =399;

        private GameThread gameThread;
        private ArrayList<Background> backgrounds = new ArrayList<>();
        private Bitmap[] bgsrc ;

        public GameController(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            bgsrc = new Bitmap[5];
            for (int i=0;i<bgsrc.length;i++){
                bgsrc[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mountain_background_v2), i*800,0,800,399);
            }
            for (int i=bgsrc.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                if (i==0 || i==2) continue;
                backgrounds.add(new Background(bgsrc[i],-10+i*2 ));
            }

            //create GameThread Object and start Thread
            gameThread = new GameThread(getHolder(),this);
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            int counter =0;
            while(retry && counter<1000){
                counter++;
                try{
                    gameThread.setRunning(false);
                    gameThread.join();retry = false;
                    gameThread = null;
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        public void update(){

               for (Background background: backgrounds){
                   background.update();
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas){
            super.draw(canvas);
            final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
            final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);
            if (canvas!=null){
                final int saveCount = canvas.save();
                canvas.scale(scaleFactorX,scaleFactorY);

                for (Background background: backgrounds){
                    background.draw(canvas);
                }
                canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

when I Draw bitmap on Canvas From Arraylist , my drawing very slow where on GameThread Class I initialized FPS(Frame per second) = 60, But After Scaling Canvas its become slow ,I already Tried scaling bitmap before drawing , but still same performance. without array i mean with single Image drawing good, How can i solve this and get exact speed what i want .. plz help me .. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The extra calls and calculations in the `draw()` causes a significant frame rate reduction. I would prefer to do all required scaling of bitmaps once, at the initialization stage, and keep the higher frame rate.

Comment: bro, Ive already Try to scaling bitmap  while Surface view Created ,, and also increase frame rate , but still same performance .. can u see this link , where i was posted with details .. help me plz.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554539/drawing-array-of-bitmap-in-canvas-is-working-slow